# Database Design: name-value pairs - good or bad?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Say I have an online store wherein each product has a single category (and there are hundreds of categories to choose from) assigned to it (e.g. "book", "portable DVD player", etc.). If I needed to provide descriptive fields for each category (e.g. "author" would be a field for the "book" category), what is the best way to represent this in a database?

Option 1 (name value pairs):

```
===========================
 field
===========================
- field_id
- category_id (FK, referring to category like "book")
- name
- value
```

This means I can rely on one table for any category. I'm concerned that the pivoting required to display this data side by side with other books might be a potential problem.

Option 2 (individual tables):

```
===========================
 book_field
===========================
- book_field_id
- book_id (FK, referring to the actual book)
- author
- title
- publisher
- date_published
...
```

This means I need a table for each category.

NOTE: not that I think it matters, but the category would be coming from a hierarchy of categories (e.g. Electronics ->  DVD Players -> Portable DVD Players).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My $0.02 - one table per category.  If things are truely different, then embrace that and set up your tables accordingly.

Naturally if some of the entities have common data, that can be abstracted/normalized out, but I think the name/value pair option you have up there could lead to some nasty readability/query performance issues down the road.

Comment: Real world note - in my work we have several types of forms that are very similar but with unique properties - we use specific tables for each, a table for some common elements (name, address, etc.), and some views that help us aggregate them when we need to view these objects together as a whole.

Comment: What Bob said.  Also search on "generalization specialization relational modeling".

Comment: Agreed. A name-value pair system makes it difficult to return a straightforward table of data with a column for each category (BookID, Author, Title, etc).

Comment: you suggested creating one table per category. What if you need to add a new category, would you have to create a new table for it? In production I would rather add a line into existing table than creating a new table. Things get tricky in object-relational mapping frameworks, like in Rails.

Comment: Ironically we're doing this in prod right now (new hospital form).  Adding a new entity generally includes rolling new UI components as well, building new ORM maps, etc. anyway so it's just a part of our user story to plug in the new table, new UI, and wire up the goodies :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to restrict only to one category. I mean, can you think of any case where you product can be belong to multiple categories?

Well, anyway here's one solution which might be usefull to you:

**UPDATE (few layers added)**

```
========
products
========
- product_id
- name

====================
categories_products
====================
- category_product_id
- product_id (FK)
- category_id (FK)

===========
categories
===========
- category_id
- name

=============================
products_detail_values_types
=============================
- product_detail_value_type_id
- product_id (FK)
- detail_value_type_id (FK)

====================
detail_values_types
====================
- detail_value_type_id
- detail_value_id (FK)
- detail_type_id (FK)

===============
detail_values
===============
- detail_value_id
- value

=============
detail_types
=============
- detail_type_id
- name
```

You have type called "director":

```
 detail_type:
   detail_type_id: 100
   name: "director"
```

And some value:

```
detail_value:
  detail_value_id: 200
  value: "James Cameron"
```

Mapping of type and value:

```
detail_value_type:
  detail_value_type_id: 300
  detail_value_id: 200
  detail_type_id: 100
```

Which details belong to product:

```
product_detail_value_type:
  product_detail_value_type: 400
  product_id: 500
  detail_value_type_id: 300
```

Then we have categories:

```
category:
  category_id: 600
  name: "movie"
```

And category-product mapping:

```
category_product:
  category_product_id: 700
  product_id: 500
  category_id: 600
```

And finally the product itself:

```
product:
  product_id: 500
  name: "Aliens"
```

Comment: @hade, now you have me a bit worried. Could a product really be in 2 categories? I've been studying Amazon a lot; not sure if I've seen such a case. Am I wrong?

Comment: @hade, this design makes it possible for me to have more than one "James Cameron." Is this normalized?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: Let's say you have category Movie. You can have movies in different formats: VHS, DVD, Blu-Ray. How would you like to categorize them? They are all movies but it would be nice to categorize them also according to the media type.

Let's say you want to search for movies in Blu-Ray format. You could do this easily by searching products in movie category and in blue-ray category.

Comment: And yes, in this design you can have more than one "James Cameron". This is quite simple example. Actually movie can have several directors, like Coen brothers. You would actually need separate people table and many-to-many relationship between details and people table. I wonder if this answer is anywhere near simple after that.

Comment: @hade, in your example, perhaps "Movie" is the category and "Blu-Ray" is a detail (like other details: director, genre, etc.). What do you think?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: I have updated the answer. I have added few layers to make it a bit more flexible. With this design your product can belong to multiple categories. And you can map detail types and values together and use them for many products. Whether you want to keep Blu-Ray as a category or detail (like a media-type), it's really up to you :).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to base your design on the one that internet tag are based on.

**Let me explain you :**

You will need 4 tables more your main object table.

*First one* : The name tag table, this is a basic table id | name, that will store attribute of object : "author", "size", "weight"; anything that can describe an object

```
tag_table
id    varchar(36)
tag   varchar(36)
```

*Second one* : This table will match the value with the tag names stored in the tag_table value. It does have the same design

```
value_table
id    varchar(36)
value varchar(36)
```

*Third one* : will determine which value is which tag.

```
tag_value
id_pair  varchar(36)
id_tag   varchar(36)
id_value varchar(36)
```

*Fourth one* : will join an Object with its data that carectrize it

```
object_tag_value
id_object  varchar(36)
id_pair    varchar(36)
```

And finally your object table.

**Implementing hierarchy system** :

For the one-to-many or many-to-many hierarchy implement an extra table that would relate the two object :

```
object_relation
id_parent varchar(36)
id_son    varchar(36)
```

For the many-to-one (Employee table with manager_id for example) just add the id_parent as a member of your object.

With this schema you will be highly scalable an object can have now an infinite characteristic you are not limited any more. Plus you avoid data redundancy because tags name are unique.

Hope I was clear enough and that it helps you,

Comment: what about hierarchy? There is no concept of hierarchy in your solution, right?

Comment: There is two concept of hierarchy 1 to many and many to many. If you need a one-to-many , pretty easy add a parentId in your object table. If it is a many-to-many add a table hierarchy with two varchar(36) fields that will be the relation between an object in the other, you can have this way an infinite of hierarchies.

Comment: if I only needed a 1 to many hierarchy, should I go with your proposed solution still?

Comment: I Modified my original post and I wrote something about hierarchy, and yes it works with your solution.